# What mechanism is used to account CPU usage for a process, particularly `sys` (time spent in kernel)

Tags: process, linux-kernel, cpu-usage

What is the mechanism used to account for cpu time, including that spent in-kernel (`sys` in the output of `top`)?

I'm thinking about limitations here because I remember reading about processes being able avoid showing up their cpu usage, if they yield before completing their time slice.

### Context

Specifically, I'm working on some existing code in KVM virtualization.

```
if (guest_tsc < tsc_deadline)
    __delay(tsc_deadline - guest_tsc);
```

The code is called with interrupts disabled.  I want to know if Linux will correctly account for long busy-waits with interrupts disabled.

If it does, it would help me worry less about certain edge case configurations which might cause long, but bounded busy-waits.  System administrators could at least notice if it was bad enough to degrade throughput (though necessarily latency), and identify the specific process responsible (in this case, QEMU, and the process ID would allow identifying the specific virtual machine).

Answer (score 0):

In Linux 4.6, I believe process times are still accounted by sampling in the timer interrupt.

```
/*
 * Called from the timer interrupt handler to charge one tick to current
 * process.  user_tick is 1 if the tick is user time, 0 for system.
 */
void update_process_times(int user_tick)
```

So it may indeed be possible for a process to game this approximation.

In answer to my specific query, it looks like CPU time spent with interrupts disabled will *not* be accounted to the specific process :(.